# How to post the viewmodel to action method using JQUERY AJAX in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I want to achieve create (INSERT) screen using $.POST or $.AJAX.

Note: code is working fine without AJAX call..it is already there.. now i need to do ajax call and save without postback.
I wrote below code:

On submit click event following is the code:

```
$.ajax(
      {
          url: '@Url.Action("CreateProduct","ProductManagement")',
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          type: 'post',
          data:   $('frm').serialize(),
          success: function () { alert('s'); },
          error: function (e1, e2, e3) { alert(e2); alert(e1 + ' ' + e2 + ' ' + e3); alert('failure event'); }
      }
    );
});
```

On server side:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateProduct(FormCollection frm)
{
    manager.ProductManager m = new manager.ProductManager();
    // m.InsertProduct(new common.DTO.ProductDTO() { Id = id, ProductName = ProductName, Description = Description, Cost = cost, ProductTypeId = 5 });
    return Json("'result':'success'", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Problem is , every time, it call the action but no data found on `frm` argument param.
i also tried to keep as - View model `ProductViewModel vm` as argument but it did not work..just giving me null value. also, in ajax call, it goes in success but. just problem is nothing posted on controller's action.

Html is as follow:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateProduct", "ProductManagement", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frm" }))
    {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>ProductViewModel</legend>
    <div id="CreateDiv">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cost)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cost)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cost)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductTypeId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ProductTypeId", "Choose item")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductTypeId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductTypeName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductTypeName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductTypeName)
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" id="btnSubmit" />
    </p>

</fieldset>
 }

 <div>
 @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </div>
```

Please guide me what is wrong here.

Thank You

Comment: On server side code you forgot to provide attribute named - **[HTTPPost]** no CreateProduct() method.

Comment: its der.. forgot to post.apologies. updated above code.

Comment: @user3711357...now getting form values???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For id Selector you have to use "#" with id.

This will work :

```
$.ajax(
  {
      url: '@Url.Action("CreateProduct","ProductManagement")',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      type: 'post',
      data:   $('this').serialize(), OR  $('#frm').serialize(),   <-----------------
      success: function () { alert('s'); },
      error: function (e1, e2, e3) { alert(e2); alert(e1 + ' ' + e2 + ' ' + e3); alert('failure event'); }
  }
 );
```

OR Try this :

```
var form = $('#frm');
$.ajax({
 cache: false,
 async: true,
 dataType: 'json',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 type: "POST",
 url: form.attr('action'),
 data: form.serialize(),
 success: function (data) {
 alert(data);
   }
 });
```

Comment: ok, tried but ,though no result... `frm.AllKeys.Count()` gives me `0` count value and no data posted. even, on view also, when i do `alert($('ProductName').val());` then it also give me undefined value. not understand what is wrong.. all worked fine without ajax.

Comment: hey try this alert($('#ProductName').val()); you re not using #

Comment: oh sorry... got the alert for correct value. but, no data posted on formcollection and it just give me count 0.

Comment: Now, i got the alert when i put `alert($('#frm').serialize)` and it shows serialize data. Now, this line `data: $('#frm').serialize(),` does not work..it gives me error alert as `internal server error` and not able to reach at action method..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58570/discussion-between-user3711357-and-exception).

Comment: then there is a problem with path just check in browser console the path generated for request???

Comment: I have changed the stuff as data: JSON.stringify({ 'f': $('#frm').serialize() }),

[HttpPost] 
public JsonResult CreateProduct(ProductViewModel f)`
able to get call the action but, f remains null only...
not understand what is wrong to post the data..

Comment: try this :data: { modelval: JSON.stringify($('#frm')) }
[HttpPost] 
public JsonResult CreateProduct(ProductViewModel modelval)`

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add id selecter:

```
$.ajax(
      {
          url: '@Url.Action("CreateProduct","ProductManagement")',
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          type: 'post',
          data:   $('#frm').serialize(),                      // $('#frm');
          success: function () { alert('s'); },
          error: function (e1, e2, e3) { alert(e2); alert(e1 + ' ' + e2 + ' ' + e3); alert('failure event'); }
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the id of your form is `frm`, then it should be referenced as follows

```
data:   $("#frm").serialize(),
```

Comment: when I first started the response you hadn't put the htlm.  It was as I suspected, the above change *will* fix the problem.

Comment: If you see that your answer becomes outdated then you can edit it at any time. This is better than adding a comment to explain why your answer no longer matches to the information provided by the OP.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  from my score you can see I just started.  I normally just read answers.  I'll get the hang of it.

Comment: You are welcome. I reviewed your first post. This is why gave you that tip ;) You can still improve your post by wrapping frm with \` instead of '. And 'references' should be 'referenced' :)

Comment: Can you show me what you mean?  I can't quite visualize that.  If you add the text instead of to the code, wouldn't it make it more difficult to read?

Comment: I mean the following: You wrote "...form is 'frm', then it...". Here you could write "...form is \`frm\`, then it..." which will format `frm` as code. This is appropriate for variable names, etc.

Comment: oh, I get it! the accent mark ` instead of the single quote '  I thought you meant inside the code block.  Cool I didn't know I could do that.  Thanks.

Comment: Again you are welcome :) If you are interested in some more tips then you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.